# В чем может быть проблема? Выдает "Частичное решение"

Tags: c++, матрицы, графы

> По заданной квадратной матрице n×n из нулей и единиц определите, может ли данная матрица быть матрицей смежности простого неориентированного графа.
>
> Входные данные
> На вход программы поступает число n (1≤n≤100)  – размер матрицы, а затем n строк по n чисел, каждое из которых равно 0 или 1, – сама матрица.
>
> Выходные данные
> Выведите  «YES», если приведенная матрица может быть матрицей смежности простого неориентированного графа, и «NO» в противном случае.
>
> ```
> > Примеры
>
>     входные данные
>     5
>     0 0 1 0 0 
>     0 0 1 0 1 
>     1 1 0 0 0 
>     0 0 0 0 0 
>     0 1 0 0 0 
>     выходные данные
>     YES
> ```

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int** mat = new int* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        mat[i] = new int[n];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
        {
            cin >> mat[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (mat[i][j] != mat[j][i])
            {
                cout << "NO";
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "YES";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        delete[] mat[i];
    }
    delete[] mat;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Может, надо смотреть еще на петли? Ну, чтоб `mat[i][i]` были нулями?

Comment: К сожалению на петли следующая задача. Тут они не предусмотрены

Answer (score 1):

У вас нет проверки на отсутствие петель.

Вот такое изменение -

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    if (mat[i][i])
    {
        cout << "NO";
        return 0;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (mat[i][j] != mat[j][i])
        {
            cout << "NO";
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

и программа благополучно проходит все тесты [здесь](https://silvertests.ru/en/CourseTask_C.aspx?id=33130&idcourse=32073).

P.S. Не понимаю, зачем задавать вопросы, если даже не готовы слушать ответы?